# BeautifulSoup fails to tag HTML correctly

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm using BeautifulSoup to parse a simple HTML table. Due to some inconsistency in the data BeautifulSoup seems to fail parsing and tagging the content correctly. Here is the code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = 1
city = 'vantaa'.capitalize()
URL = 'https://asuntojen.hintatiedot.fi/haku/?cr=1&t=3&l=0&search=1&sf=0&so=a&renderType=renderTypeTable&print=1&z={}&c={}'.format(page, city)
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
tables = soup.find_all('tbody', attrs={'class':'odd'})
table = max(tables, key=len)
rows = table.find_all('tr')
```

One correctly tagged row looks like this:

```
<tr>
    <td class="area">Area 1</td>
    <td>Random string 1+1q, d</td>
    <td class="type">xb</td>
    <td class="cellAlignRight">38,00</td>
    <td class="cellAlignRight">132000</td>
    <td class="cellAlignRight">3474</td>
    <td class="cellAlignRight">1661</td>
    <td>1/1</td>
    <td>no</td>
    <td>less.</td>
    <td>oma
    <td>G<sub>2013</sub></td>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

However in the middle of the document something fails and the last rows are merged into one huge string

```
<tr>
    <td class="neighborhood">Itä-hakkila</td>
    <td>1h, avokeitti&amp;#...&lt;/td&gt;
      &lt;td class="houseType"&gt;rt&lt;/td&gt;
      &lt;td class="cellAlignRight"&gt;21,50&lt;/td&gt;
      &lt;td class="cellAlignRight"&gt;149000&lt;/td&gt;
      &lt;td class="cellAlignRight"&gt;6930&lt;/td&gt;
      &lt;td class="cellAlignRight"&gt;2017&lt;/td&gt;
      &lt;td&gt;1/2&lt;/td&gt;
      &lt;td&gt;ei&lt;/td&gt;
      &lt;td&gt;hyvä&lt;/td&gt;
      &lt;td&gt;oma &lt;td&gt;C&lt;sub&gt;2013&lt;/sub&gt;&lt;/td&gt;
      &lt;/tr&gt;
      &lt;tr&gt;
      &lt;td class="neighborhood"&gt;Kivist&amp;#246;&lt;/td&gt;
      &lt;td&gt;1h+kt&lt;/td&gt;
      &lt;td class="houseType"&gt;kt&lt;/td&gt;
      &lt;td class="cellAlignRight"&gt;27,00&lt;/td&gt;
      &lt;td class="cellAlignRight"&gt;132000&lt;/td&gt;
      &lt;td class="cellAlignRight"&gt;4889&lt;/td&gt;
      &lt;td class="cellAlignRight"&gt;2018&lt;/td&gt;
      &lt;td&gt;5/6&lt;/td&gt;
      &lt;td&gt;on&lt;/td&gt;
      &lt;td&gt;hyvä&lt;/td&gt;
      &lt;td&gt;vuokra &lt;td&gt;C&lt;sub&gt;2013&lt;/sub&gt;&lt;/td&gt;
      &lt;/tr&gt;
```

which seems to be caused by this cell `1h, avokeitti&#...`, which BeautifulSoup turns into `<td>1h, avokeitti&amp;#...&lt;/td&gt;` where as in the actual HTML on the webpage there is no such issue

```
<tr>
    <td class="neighborhood">It&#228;-hakkila</td>
    <td>1h, avokeitti&#...</td>
    <td class="houseType">rt</td>
    <td class="cellAlignRight">21,50</td>
    <td class="cellAlignRight">149000</td>
    <td class="cellAlignRight">6930</td>
    <td class="cellAlignRight">2017</td>
    <td>1/2</td>
    <td>ei</td>
    <td>hyvä</td>
    <td>oma                         <td>C<sub>2013</sub></td>
</tr>
```

I've tried using `unicode.unescape()` to the whole table which gives `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`, I've tried using `re.sub(r'&lt;', '<', text)` to clean the whole table or single rows but that gives `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`.

I circumvented this issue by just doing `df_list  = pd.read_html(page.text)` to get the table out as a dataframe (and had to deal with other formatting issues instead), but the original issue was not solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It parses this HTML correctly with parser `html5lib`

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html5lib")
```

It may need to install module `html5lib` using `pip`

---

See more information about different parsers in documentation: [Installing a parser](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#installing-a-parser)

There is table with `advantages` and `disadvantages`.

Comment: Somehow didn't even think that the parser could be changed. This solves the original issue in case I encounter it again and cannot use (or don't want to use) pandas.